# Can I access stack memory from main() after calling QApplication.exec()?

Tags: segmentation-fault

I have the segmentation fault when I try to the stack memory outside of main after I call QApplication.exec()

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include "Controller.hpp"
#include "QtMainGui.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // instantiate one controller -- this Controller inherits QApplication
    Controller theController(arg, argv);
    QSharedPointer<Controller> theSharedPointerController(&theController);

    // instantiate the QtMainGui
    QtMainGui qtMainGui;

    qtMainGui.show()
    qtMainGui.saveTheController(theSharedPointerController);

    ........

    return theController.exec();

}
```